# Python while not true loops

Tags: python, function, if-statement, while-loop

```
door = input("Do you want to open the door? Enter yes or no: ").lower()

while door != "yes" and door != "no":
    print("Invalid answer.")
    door = input("Do you want to open the door? Enter yes or no: ").lower()

if door == "yes":
    print("You try to twist open the doorknob but it is locked.")
elif door == "no":
    print("You decide not to open the door.")
```

Is there an easier way to use the while loop for invalid answers? So I won't need to add that line after every single question in the program.

I tried def() and while true, but not quite sure how to use the them correctly.

Comment: Show us the `def` approach you tried? It's a good idea to encapsulate the logic in a function (and you need to know how to write functions.) Also a `do while` might be good here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to avoid the extra line:

```
while True
    door = input("Do you want to open the door? Enter yes or no: ").lower()
    if door in ("yes", "no"):
        break
    print("Invalid answer.")
```

Or if you do this a lot make a helper function.

```
def get_input(prompt, error, choices):
    while True:
        answer = input(f"{prompt} Enter {', '.join(choices)}: ")
        if answer in choices:
            return answer
        print(error)
```

Example usage:

```
door = get_input("Do you want to open the door?", "Invalid answer.", ("yes", "no"))
if door == "yes":
    print("You try to twist open the doorknob but it is locked.")
else:
    print("You decide not to open the door.")
```

Comment: But how do I also incorporate the other if and elif statements?

Comment: @fuwubuki Updated with an example.

Answer (score -1):

```
while True:
    answer = ("Enter yes or no: ").lower()
    if answer in ["yes", "no"]:
        break
    print("Invalid answer.")
    # loop will repeat again
```